# Download offline maps with Android Mapbox SDK

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Android Mapbox SDK support offline downloads (https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/offline-manager/). I've setup my own verctor tile server with OpenMapTiles (https://openmaptiles.org/). Does offline functionality work with your own tile server, or is it only supported when using mapbox tiles?

Answer (score 1):

If your tile server is using the same [vector tile specification](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/) and they load up correctly inside the mapview while online, you shouldn't have any issues.

Just a note that very soon we will be adding a document walking through the offline API here. https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/5.0.1/getting-started/

Comment: Was looking for an update on this? Does Mapbox SL support offline maps for 3rd party tile sources?